# How to edit default input source language in mac os x?

Tags: macos, arabic

I want to edit the Arabic language Input source to make it type English numbers instead of Arabic numbers is there is anyway to do that ?

Comment: You could create your custom layout - http://superuser.com/questions/665494/how-to-make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-in-os-x